# Cloud datastore client changes type from int to float

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-cloud-datastore

I was writing a script in python using google-cloud-datastore python module to upload data from my CSV to datastore. The script seems to work fine but There seems to be a problem that I'm stuck with. I see that the integer values from my CSV are being stored as Floating point number. Is it a default way of sending data to datastore or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import getopt

import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import datastore

def write_dict_chunks(data, SIZE=100):
    log_count = 0
    datastore_client = datastore.Client()
    task_key = datastore_client.key(kind)
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), SIZE):
        entities = []
        for each_entry in data[i : i+SIZE]:
            nan_check = lambda v: v if str(v)!='nan' else None
            string_check = lambda v: v.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, str) else v
            write_row = {k: nan_check(string_check(v)) for k, v in each_entry.iteritems()}
            entity = datastore.Entity(key=task_key)
            entity.update(write_row)
            entities.append(entity)
        datastore_client.put_multi(entities)
        log_count += len(entities)
        print 'Wrote {} entities to datastore'.format(log_count)
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "ho:v", ["kind=", "filepath="])
    if len(args) > 0:
        for each in args:
            print 'Unrecognized argument: '+each
        sys.exit(2)
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    # print help information and exit:
    print str(err)  # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
    print 'Usage: python parse_csv.py --kind=kind_name --filepath=path_to_csv'

kind = None
filepath = None

for option, argument in opts:
    if option in '--kind':
        kind = argument
    elif option in '--filepath':
        filepath = argument

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df = df.to_dict(orient='records')

write_dict_chunks(df)
```

Comment: Can you show your CSV data or similar data which cause same issue? (Aside to that, I want to recommend this tool: https://github.com/nshmura/dsio)

Comment: Sorry I cannot. The data is sensitive. But I can tell you that it was exported as csv from BigQuery where the datatype of that column was INTEGER.

Comment: I guess read_csv returns string values. You can check the type of value by printing `type(v)`.